# edge browser Could not locate https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-cache/4.6.0/dist/angular-cache.js specified in source map

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge

I have an application which made by AngularJS, it is working fine in all browsers except Windows Edge browser and it shows error,

The source URL in my code is: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-cache/4.6.0/angular-cache.min.js 
and I did check the code and nothing mentioned about this URL  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-cache/4.6.0/angular-cache.min.js and I have no idea where the Edge browser brings this URL.

I should make this bold again, in other browsers do not have this issue at all.

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZlD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is caused by multiple "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" entries in the response header.

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: sessionToken
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, trader-session-token

This causes Edge to ignore the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, trader-session-token" entry.